# Typo in the site FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, faq-for-site

There are two typos in moderator-maintained part of the [site FAQ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

> A note on programming-related questions: general programming questions more likely belong on StackOverflow instead of here. (…)

The name of the site is missing a space, and the link is broken (the URL is `stackoverflow`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch! I also edited a bit for aesthetics. I really like the note about programming questions:

> A note on programming-related questions: general programming questions more likely belong on Stack Overflow instead of here. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself …
>
> > Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?

Which is an excellent way to explain the difference!